# using multiple .replace calls on an array of variables in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a tool that would receive text that has been copied from a word document, and return an `html` output for copy/paste into an email client for email marketing.

During this process, one of the steps the tool needs to handle is the replacement of special characters within the copied values. The output needs to show the encoded values so when they are copied into the email client, they render accordingly during the mail send process

The problem is that there are multiple inputs the user can populate and right now the code is **VERY WET**... I want to set up the tool to be a little cleaner, and not repeat the code as often.

Currently the input is given to the tool via a `prompt();`

I am taking that input and replacing the special characters ™, ®, Ø, ´, ”, ‟ and others (partial list given for this example) as needed:

JS (Commented Version)

```
msg2 = prompt("enter text here");
  //long version to tag each replacement with it's identifying name
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u0027]/g, '&amp;#39;'); // Apostrophe ´
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u2122]/g, '&amp;#153;'); // trademark ™
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u00AE]/g, '&amp;#174;'); // R-Ball ®
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u201c]/g, '&amp;#34;'); // Left Double Quote ‟
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u201D]/g, '&amp;#34;'); // Right Double Quote ”
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u2018]/g, '&amp;#39;'); // Left Single Quote ‛
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u2019]/g, '&amp;#39;'); // Right Single Quote ’
  msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u2022]/g, '&amp;#2022;') // Bullet •
```

JS (Short Version)

```
msg2 = prompt("enter text here");

msg2 = msg2.replace(/[\u0027]/g, '&amp;#39;').replace(/[\u2122]/g,
 '&amp;#153;').replace(/[\u00AE]/g, '&amp;#174;').replace(/[\u201c]/g,
 '&amp;#34;').replace(/[\u201D]/g, '&amp;#34;').replace(/[\u2018]/g,
 '&amp;#39;').replace(/[\u2019]/g, '&amp;#39;').replace(/[\u2022]/g,
 '&amp;#2022;');
```

BUT... I need to run this same replacement on a number of prompts. I don't want to repeat this in the code a bunch of times with each of the variables changing as needed.

What I would rather do is create a function to handle the replacement, and then simply create an array of the variables and run the function on the array...

Example

```
function txtEncode () {        
    ...replacment code here...
    }


var inputTxt = [msg1, msg2, msg3...];
    for (var i=0; i < inputTxt.length; i++){
        txtEncode(i)
    }
```

Comment: why can't you just do what you suggested?  create a method and place your replace logic in it?

Comment: .. i think the point is i am uncertain how to implement what i suggested... i know i should do it... hence why i suggested it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make an array with replacement pairs:

```
var replacements = [ ["&", "&amp;"], ["'", "&quot;"] etc
```

and apply them one by one:

```
replacements.forEach(function(pair) {
     msg = msg.split(pair[0]).join(pair[1]);
});
```

`split/join` is better to replace literal strings than `.replace` which is intended for use with regular expressions.

Also, your encoding doesn't look right, `&amp;#174;` will be displayed as `&#174;`, not as ®

Comment: Possible pitfall with the '&' and '&amp;', if that evaluates after there are already escaped values in the message you would break it

Comment: @Rich: that's why I put it first.

Comment: Yea understandable, just figured it should be mentioned as the assumption that makes that work is that no escapes would already exist (as in pre-existing in the input).

Comment: the &amp;#174; is correct... I need the output to be a string that is copy/pasted into the email client. The output would encode the first &amp; into an ampersand leaving a copy-able code of &#174;. Once that is pasted into the email client, the encoding happens again leaving a true r-ball ® in the copy on screen in the email as sent.

Comment: I will have to look into split/join as I am unfamiliar with it.. but this seems viable as well. Thank you. The regex always tripped me up!

Comment: I set up a function following your lead and it worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global find/replace function and extend the string prototype, I have this code in one of my fiddles, but I can't find the origin.

Code:

```
String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
  var replaceString = this;
  var regex; 
  for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
    regex = new RegExp(find[i], "g");
    replaceString = replaceString.replace(regex, replace[i]);
  }
  return replaceString;
};

var msg2 = 'demo \u0027'
var find = ["\u0027"];
var replace = ["&amp;#39;"];
msg2 = msg2.replaceArray(find, replace);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/YQKwN/

Comment: this would work if i only had to replace one special character in the string.. I have to search for 20+ characters in 6-7 different strings.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method to the String object for your code.

```
String.prototype.myCleanString = function(){
    return this.replace(/[\u0027]/g, '&amp;#39;')
                .replace(/[\u2122]/g,'&amp;#153;')
                .replace(/[\u00AE]/g, '&amp;#174;')
                .replace(/[\u201c]/g, '&amp;#34;')
                .replace(/[\u201D]/g, '&amp;#34;')
                .replace(/[\u2018]/g, '&amp;#39;')
                .replace(/[\u2019]/g, '&amp;#39;')
                .replace(/[\u2022]/g, '&amp;#2022;')
                .replace(/foo/g, 'bar'); 
}
```

Call as needed... http://jsfiddle.net/XKHNt/